Is subjectivist epistemology the proximate cause of adverse social conditions?
The Crisis of Subjectivist Epistemology

Epistemology has to do with how we know, subjectivity refers to the supremacy of the individual’s feelings or experience. A subjectivist epistemology refers to the act of his experience to determine what counts as truth or knowledge.

Political-economic outcomes are the product of a complex process wherein each agent in the population makes decisions under uncertainty, and takes action, based on the agent's implicit cognitive experience. The interaction of subjective agents produces a mix of good and bad outcomes based on the subjective evaluations of each respective agent as to which outcomes they report as good and which outcomes they report as bad. Recently, some noted thinkers have begun asserting that in the West, there's an overemphasis on the subjective that leads to social ills.
One such thinker is Jonathan Haidt who in his The Coddling of the American Mind claims that using your feelings as a basis for your beliefs is socially problematic. Another is Steven Pinker who in his The Blank Slate attacks the relativism of the Standard Social Science Model as harmful since it undercuts objectivity. Are such thinkers being irrational or unreasonable when blaming adverse social outcomes on implicit subjective knowledge when good social outcomes are also produced by implicit subjective knowledge?

Eliminated your personal beliefs and added some examples of critiques of modern subjectivism in the West to stave off closure. Feel free to roll back.

These authors would only be irrational, and guilty of cherry picking evidence, if they singled out the downsides of subjectivism and based their conclusions on those alone. But the standard SSM being standard, the upsides are well documented and defended, so the argument, presumably, is that they do not outweigh the downsides according to these authors. Generally, arguments of this sort can only be valid when they involve cost/benefit analysis, but sometimes one side of it or the other is only implicit.

@Conifold Cost/benefit analysis may be justified as rational but it would only be objectively valid if there is a politically non-controversial means to specify intrinsic value. Subjective versus Objective Value: The Economist and The Philosopher: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PeRBsEyakU. The clip asserts that economists recognize subjective value (subjective utility) whereas philosophers advocate for political institutions based on the effort to recognize objective values. Reciprocal rights & duties might be taken as objective based on our shared subjective experience of intrinsic value.

There is no need for something as lofty as objective values, some intersubjective agreement on "social ills" is enough and easier to come by. It can, of course, be disputed whether this or that is an "ill" or a "good" but that is a separate issue from whether cultural subjectivism tends to bring about more of the former than of the latter. And that cost/benefit analysis can, in principle, rationally determine.

Are you sure you mean the proximate cause and not something like an important contributing cause?

May you clarify what do you mean with "adverse social conditions"? Poverty? Due to epistemology???

@g s Legal opinions make distinctions between remote or ultimate causes and nearby or proximate causes. A proximate cause can be a sole cause or a joint cause, that is, the combination of two or more sole causes. Legal opinions also make distinctions between natural events and events caused by moral agents. People who argue that subjective experience is a cause of social ills are stating a kind of map or relation: subjective experience causes social ills. I use the term proximate cause to make the substance of this subjective moralistic judgment or subjective opinion more obvious and explicit.

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA The alarmists who identify human subjectivity as a social crisis are the ones who recognize adverse social outcomes. In my worldview there are only subjects processing sensory information based on respective implicit cognitive experience. The decisions, actions, and moral judgments arise as the product of the implicit subjective cognitive process. I do not reject theories that our cognitive process is similar based on similarities in the human body and nervous system. The assertion that subjectivity is a cause of social crisis seems to be the product of a subjective process.

It's subjective all the way down.

Nietzsche's minimalist take on subjective epistemology is "perspectivity", i.e. from The Will to Power (1901), § 481

To the extent to which knowledge has any sense at all, the world is
knowable: but it may be interpreted differently, it has not one
sense behind it, but hundreds of senses.—"Perspectivity."

but as Edgar Sleinis observes in Nietzsche's Revaluation of Values: A Study in Strategies (1994), p. 59

[Nietzsche's] position is not that any view is as good as any other
view either in regard to value judgements or to judgements about the
world.  In considering values, we cannot do better than perspectival
truth, but we can certainly do worse. There are still better perspectives and worse perspectives, and these need to be sorted by
subjecting them to rational scrutiny. Provided only that one desires
to maximise value, the ground is set for an inquiry into how such
desire can be met.

If "rational scrutiny" were neglected and inconvenient truths ignored that would lead to suboptimal value in regard to quality of understanding.

Jesus said to love God and your neighbor. And man cannot serve two masters. Nietzsche said we killed God so man should love his fate and become his own master! Sigmund Freud said the human ego is helpless in early life and serves two harsh masters: the internal id and external reality! The biological ego strives to love, because love makes the ego happy, and the mature ego strives to cope with the hostile attributes of natural reality. Webster's defines prudence as the ability to govern action by the use of reason. Freud's value is prudence: the ego's ability to love and work well with others.

I think the question is a bit subjective, and that would make it a proximate cause of closure, but let's riff a little on subjectivism according to two notable psychologically inclined thinkers: Kahneman and McGilchrist, both minor philosophers as well as scientists.
You ask:

Is subjectivist epistemology the proximate cause of adverse social conditions?

There is a tension between subjectivity and objectivity that has been a central theme of philosophy for thousands of years. The clash between classical empiricists and rationalists is a reflection of that tension. And Comte's positivism as a doctrine crescendoed with the failure of the logical positivists to create something like an observation statement that stripped subjectivity from science. Phenomenology, on the other hand also represented a progressive move forward as it attempts to determine what is objective about being subjective. Merleau-Ponty goes after the two modes of thought in his Phenomenology of Perception. Add to the mix the idea that objectivity is nothing but intersubjectivity, and you have quite a complicated affair.
The question is does a "subjectivist epistemology" cause adverse social conditions is a bit misleading, then, because all epistemology starts with the subjectivity and while we might aspire to objectivity, objectivity might be nothing more than a clever abstraction to hide our values. Certainly, many philosophers have attacked the fact-value dichotomy in various ways. Some thinkers who are informing the issue are psychologists, who are taking a close look at the psychological origin of reason and emotion.
In Kahneman's Thinking, Fast and Slow, we are presented with two systems of thinking, a fast and reactive thinking, and a slower, rational system. Clearly, objectivity as we understand it is built from the the rational system. Modern sciences, be they natural, social, or formal, rely heavily on reason and formal logic. In fact, the explosion of reason as both a practice and a virtue is the backbone of the Age of Enlightenment.
Thus, objectivity is held up as a virtue, and men and women and everyone else rely on the rule of law, logic, and technology to be impartial. The topic is sort important to the cognitive scientist Pinker, he went on to defend the value of objectivity (indirectly) in both his Enlightenment Now and Rationality.
Of course, objectivity may not be all that it's cracked up to be. As both Ludwik Fleck and Thomas Kuhn have argued, science isn't as fair and objective as some proponents have claimed. Advancing Marx's theories, the Critical Theorists (SEP) have done a good job of raising the alarm on fundamental inequalities and inequities in otherwise "objective" and "fair" systems. It's an easy dodge to convert one's wishes to "objective reality" or "God's will" or anything that effaces the subjectivity of thought.
Thus, it is not subjectivism proper that is the problem, according to some, but the lack of balance between subjectivism and objectivity. One such thinker who maintains this position is Iain McGilchrist who argued in his The Master and His Emissary that there is a conflict in each of us between divisive cognitive abilities and that society is moving towards being increasingly unbalanced as a result. From the article:

These two modes of perception cascade into wildly different hemispheric personalities, and in fact reflect yet a further asymmetry in their status, that of the right's more immediate relationship with physical bodies (our own as well as others) and external reality as represented by the senses, a relationship that makes it the mediator, the first and last stop, of all experience... the author describes the evolution of Western culture, as influenced by hemispheric brain functioning, from the ancient world, through the Renaissance and Reformation; the Enlightenment; Romanticism and Industrial Revolution; to the modern and postmodern worlds which, to our detriment, are becoming increasingly dominated by the left brain.

Thus, it is not emotions or reasons, or subjectivity or objectivity that is the problem, but an imbalance between such valences that creates dysfunction. And that imbalance applies to individuals in a society too. If people are so enamored with their own feelings and subjective thinking that they cannot participate in a common good or mutually beneficial society, then society indeed suffers. Perhaps this is another lamentable dissolution of the public sphere, adding a dimension to Habermas's concerns.

I like the answer. I was reminded of Julian Jaynes's book, "The Origin of Consciousness in the Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind". I think subjectivity is fine, as long as we end up agreeing on things.

@ScottRowe My feelings tell me youre wrong. ; ) Thanks for the title! Sounds interesting.

Ill drop this here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Origin_of_Consciousness_in_the_Breakdown_of_the_Bicameral_Mind?wprov=sfla1

Baruch Spinoza says the greatest good is for men to unite, one with another, in the bonds of common reason. But I don't recall his description of reason. He also says man is to man as God. Taking God as the Giver of Life I think this is psychologically true for dependent children and for adults who cannot remedy intense pain, disability, or avoid death without the help of others. Spinoza describes an affect (emotion) as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. He describes desire as appetite accompanied by consciousness thereof. Subjectivity is the reality!

"Wem der große Wurf gelungen
Eines Freundes Freund zu sein;
Wer ein holdes Weib errungen
Mische seinen Jubel ein!
Ja, wer auch nur eine Seele
Sein nennt auf dem Erdenrund!
Und wer's nie gekonnt, der stehle
Weinend sich aus diesem Bund!" "Let the man who has had the fortune
To be a helper to his friend,
And the man who has won a noble woman,
Join in our chorus of jubilation!
Yes, even if he holds but one soul
As his own in all the world!
But let the man who knows nothing of this
Steal away alone and in sorrow." An die Freude, Schiller

"Bei mir bist du Schon!" (it's the only phrase I know in that language) Just heard Beethoven's 9th a week ago.


Political-economic outcomes are the product of a complex process wherein each agent in the population makes decisions under uncertainty, and takes action, based on the agent's implicit cognitive experience.

Not even that. They can be the result of chance. They can be caused by group decisions. They can be caused by individual decisions. They can be caused by individuals by accident (idk Brian might have accidentally burned down the harvest) or they might be deliberate by an individual action (the king ruled one should harvest the new crop) or they might be collectively caused (idk the plenum came to the decision one should do this and that) or they might be the result of simple individual actions that grow up to group patterns. Idk how swarm animal movement might be the result of individuals trying to keep a certain distance or proximity to only their very nearest neighbor, but if everyone does it looks like a collective movement.
So to attribute that in general terms to one particular cause sounds majorly unreasonable, though if it's a specific example and a specific cause it might not be unreasonable.
As Chris has pointed out we can only assess our environment through the lens of the subject, so for better or worse the best we can do is consider as many different perspectives, yet our ability to do so is still tied to our own perspective. So "objectivity" is rather an illusion or the attempt to paint a picture by looking at all the different dots that are created by other people's perspectives (filtered through one's own).
So the subjective undercuts the objective is a false dichotomy as you can't get one without the other.
Also even if you would want to try you can't really give yourself up to the swarm without reducing yourself from a subject to an object (usually death), which means to think "objectively" would come at the price of not thinking at all as that's what subjects do.
Also if society reacts adverse to the subject the subject is forced to think subjectively so to command them to reason and to "think objectively" is asinine. While you have a working collective of people and a group process that requires participation, yet if everyone goes towards their own goal making that synergy of the group come to an end, it might actually be reasonable to remind people of the subjective benefit of actions that go beyond the subject and that might not have been subjectively obvious.

+1 "So the subjective undercuts the objective is a false dichotomy as you can't get one without the other." Also, wir erinnern uns an die Worte Wittgensteins wer sagt "Die Grenzen meiner Sprache bedeuten die Grenzen meiner Welt." Which is why all intelligence boils down to type theory (meiner Meinung nach). ; )

It is a compelling answer. Perhaps reality is ultimately composed of random interactions of matter and radiation. If so, then the moral subject who asserts that events are products of a random process, call it the cosmic crapshoot, remains a moral subject in the subjective experience! Some people hear the voice of God. Others claim to recognize only random interactions of matter and radiation! The matter and radiation in my body and the whole universe somehow makes decisions under uncertainty and takes action. I take this to be my implicit cognitive experience not the experience of others.

I consider the content of the above link a clear description of “wishful thinking”. Wishful thinking does not interpret the phenomena in a neutral manner, but with a strong bias.
Hence wishful thinking is never a philosophical method, being part of a sound epistemology. Independently whether its results become true or false in a given situation.
If I remember correctly the clip does not use the term “implicit” subjective knowledge.

The clip does not use the term "implicit". If knowledge is implicit in a respective brain, or embodied mind, or intelligent social agent, then objective knowledge is the subdomain of implicit subjective knowledge which the agents attempt to make explicit using language and other meaningful modes of self-other communication. The encoding and decoding of meaning is implicit or subjective yet we recognize some knowledge as objective in context. Autopsy Einstein's brain but one could not reverse engineer or decode his implicit knowledge by studying the explicit structures of his nervous system.
